# Random marker on google maps Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to create a map where I can loop through an array of different locations. Then I want to set out the position of a random coordinate. So I want one coordinate to place a marker for me randomly each time I reload the page!

```
    function initialize() {
    //here is the starting for the map, where it will begin to show
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.2982762, 17.9970823);

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
      //below are the markers coordinates, change it to your coordinates
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),  myOptions);

        var i = 0;
        function randAreas() {
        var flagAreas = (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5);
    }

      var flagAreas = [

      [59.2967322, 18.0009393],
      [59.2980245, 17.9971503],
      [59.2981078, 17.9980875],
      [59.2982762, 17.9970823],
      [59.2987638, 17.9917639],
      [59.2987649, 17.9917824],
      [59.2987847, 17.9917731],
      [59.2988498, 17.991684],
      [59.2988503, 17.9981593],
      [59.3008233, 18.0041763],
      [59.3014033, 18.0068793],
      [59.3016619, 18.0137766]
      ];

    return flagAreas;

    flagAreas.sort(randAreas);

      //script counts the array of coordinates
      //for (var i = 0; i < flagAreas.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(flagAreas[i], flagAreas[i]),
          map: map,
        });
      }

 window.onload = initialize;

</script>
```

Comment: there is error with for loop

Comment: The for loop doesn't run, it is commented out.

Comment: There's a lot more wrong with that code than the loop.

Comment: @Polpotkinz yes, but check the end curly braces of for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, move your map variable outside of initialize in case you need to use it elsewhere in your code.

```
var map;

function initialize() {

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.2982762, 17.9970823);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),  myOptions);

  var flagAreas = [
    [59.2967322, 18.0009393], [59.2980245, 17.9971503],
    [59.2981078, 17.9980875], [59.2982762, 17.9970823],
    [59.2987638, 17.9917639], [59.2987649, 17.9917824],
    [59.2987847, 17.9917731], [59.2988498, 17.991684],
    [59.2988503, 17.9981593], [59.3008233, 18.0041763],
    [59.3014033, 18.0068793], [59.3016619, 18.0137766]
  ];
```

Shuffle the flagAreas and grab the first array.

```
  var random = flagAreas.sort(function () { return Math.random() - 0.5 } )[0];
```

Add the marker.

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(random[0], random[1]),
    map: map,
  });

}

window.onload = initialize;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22M4L/34/)

Comment: I get an unexpected identifier on this line var random = flagAreas.sort(function() Math.random() - 0.5)[0];

Comment: It might be because of the missing curly brackets. I updated the answer. Otherwise that should work fine - check out the fiddle.

Comment: This doesn't work, it doesn't run through the array it just takes the first element in the array and set a marker for that coordinate, it doesn't randomize

Comment: I forgot the `return`.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't have to run through the array. It shuffles the array and takes the first element.

Comment: I would create the markers with a loop and push them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems in your code.

1) Unexpected termination of the **`initialize`** without executing the **`for`** loop.

```
 return flagAreas;  //Remove this code
```

2)

```
flagAreas[i] //An array returns both lat and lng

position: new google.maps.LatLng(flagAreas[i], flagAreas[i]) //Wrong
```

Replace like

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(flagAreas[i][0], flagAreas[i][1]) //Correct
```

3) Remove `,` whenever you reach the last option.

```
 map: map
```

Finally check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/3034/)

Comment: Thank you. The problem isn't the for loop because I don't use it. I want the MathRandom to choose a coordinate for me randomly and then place a marker on the map on page load.

Comment: Sorry my mistake didn't see the curly brackets. But it doesn't randomize, it just takes the first coordinate in the array. [link](http://jimkollevik.se/google_map/random.html)